# Trying to find eigenfunctions for the D.E. $y''+λy=0$ with B.C. $y'(0)=y'(π)=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, eigenfunctions

The way of solution which I followed is:

Setting $\lambda=k^2$

I get

$y'' + k^2y=0$

which gives

$y(x)=Asin(kx)+Bcos(kx)$

Taking the 1st derivative

$y'(x)=kAcos(kx)-kBsin(kx)$

I apply the BC

$y'(0)=kA=0$ and $y'(\pi)=-kA=0$

which both give $A=0$ and the solution becomes

$y(x)=Bcos(kx)$

Differentiating again

$y'(x)=-kBsin(kx)$

and applying the BC again

$y'(0)=-kBsin(0)=0$ which is true $\forall$ k

and

$y'(\pi)=-kBsin(k\pi)=0$ which must give

$sin(k\pi)=0\Rightarrow k\pi=n\pi\Rightarrow k=n$

so the eigenfunctions are

$y_n(x)=Bcos(nx)$ for $n=\pm1,\pm2,\pm3...$

Can somebody please ensure that this way is right? Should or should not $x$ be a part of eigenfunction formula?

Comment: If $\lambda>0$, there are no such eigenfunctions.

Comment: Could you please explain why?

Comment: Sorry I had to write $\lambda <0$. Because if $\lambda=-1$ then $ e^x$ is a solution.

Comment: The way you phrased the question is confusing and appears to not be coherent. You ask about the eigenfunctions of the equation, but equations do not have eigenfunctions. We talk about the eigenfunctions of a linear operator, not of an equation. Perhaps you meant to talk about the solutions of the equation satisfying the boundary conditions you presented. Alternatively, you can talk about the linear operator $L$ such that $L[y]=y''.$ Then you can talk about the eigenfunctions of $L.$ You would frame that question as solving the equation $L[y]=\lambda{y},$ so you would let $\lambda=-k^2.$

Comment: In that case, you would indeed have $y(x)=A\sin(kx)+B\cos(kx)$, and so the eigenfunctions would indeed be given by $y(x)=B\cos(nx)$ with $\lambda=-n^2.$